# Transparent video in html5

Tags: javascript, html, html5-video, mp4, video-processing

I have a transparent background video in mp4 format. I am trying to add this video in html. Video gets added every time but nothing shows on screen, but this video works fine in vlc player. I have converted this video from flv to mp4.
I have tried another mp4 videos as well, they are working but not this one.

Comment: "I have tried another mp4 videos as well, they are working but not this one." So the problem is probably the video.

Comment: I know the problem, kindly tell me the solution.

Comment: can you paste your problem statement with code

Comment: there is o problem with the code as I said other mp4 videos are working, but this video has a transparent background. But still I'll paste my code.

Comment: <video controls>
 <source src="one.mp4" video="video/mp4">
</video>

Comment: @raj no one can "tell you the solution" without having more details about your problem. How is your MP4 rendered ? Can you give us a VideoSpec dump ?

Comment: Basic issue is that there is no transparency in mp4 video. You can get alpha transparencies in gif and animated png formats, but not video files.

Answer (score 1):

I recommend you to simply use a `gif`. I'm not sure if I understood your problem right. But normally `mp4` does not support transparent backgrounds. `GIF` does. If you want sound to it, you will need to play the sound file of it manually in the code.

Comment: The downside to this approach would be how large the file size of the gif would be.

Answer (score 1):

`MP4` videos doesn't supports alpha channels, so you can't use a `MP4` to get a transparent background.

You might use `webm` instead. [Here is some details about](https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2013/07/Alpha-transparency-in-Chrome-video) `webm` from Google. Not all browser supports `webm`, here is a [support list](https://caniuse.com/#feat=webm).

If you really want to use `MP4` here is a javascript library that can do this : [seeThru](https://github.com/m90/seeThru)

> Your HTML5 video source is re-rendered into a canvas-element, adding
>   the possibility to use transparencies in your video. Alpha information
>   is either included in the video's source file (moving) or in a
>   seperate -element (static).

It works pretty well on HTML5 desktop browsers (even IE9).

Answer (score 0):

mp4's and most other common video formats don't support alpha transparency.

What you would need to do is identify the background color of the website you're embedding the video in and set the background color of the video to that when your encode it.

Comment: Is there any way I can send you guys the video? than tell me the solution

Comment: I just told you the solution.

Comment: I am embedding the video on simple html page on my laptop. So I can set background color manually.